# What is wrong with my solution here, joining array elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm new to JavaScript, I'm sorry if the question is dumb.

The task:
Declare a function called join that can take two inputs: 1) an array and 2) a separator string. The separator string is optional.

join concatenates all the elements of the input array with the input string and returns the result. The output of join is always a string.

This is my code but it's not passing, what am I doing wrong?

```
var myName = ["firstname", "lastname"];

function join(arr, separator) {
  console.log(join.split)
}
```

The error is: The join function joins items of a given array with a given separator string

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your function currently doesn't do anything with the arguments passed in, and returns nothing. 
I've put a little example together to illustrate what I mean. I hope it helps you to finish the assignment.

```
var myName = ['firstName', 'lastName'];

function join(arr, separator) {

    var result;

    // Do something with arr and separator, in this case I log it
    console.log(arr, separator);

    // return the result, in this case it should be the string you need to build
    return result;

}

// Call the function to test it
// join(['hello', 'world'], ', ') should output "Hello, world"

============

Example:

function multiply(number, times) {
    return number * times; // this returns the multiplication
}

multiply(5, 10); // 50

function multiply2(number, times) {
    number * times; // This doesn't return anything
}

multiply2(3999, 1234); // undefined
```